# Standard font sizes business cards

Tags: print-design, typography, text

i'm having a discussing with a colleague at the office about font size on business cards. Does someone know's what are the standard font sizes for name, contact details etc. ? Or some values. He's using 6 - 7 points for text and for name around 10 points. and i was saying it should be a bit bigger.

Comment: There is no standard that I am aware of but I would personally not go lower than 10pt.

Comment: 10 for contacts 12 for name ? ȘD

Comment: This question is somewhat opinion based... will also depend on the font being used

Comment: not really sure why i got a - when i asked a question. I came here to ask the question because i knew i would find more answers than from any article.. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard size for such thing.
Font size also differs per font, since readability per font is very different. It depends on the general design of the card as well.

For most fonts I would say 6-7 is too small though.
I like to stick around 9-10 but this again depends on the font and the amount of information I need to put on the card.